# CloudWatch Query join two records having same id

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a cloudwatch log in the following format

| id | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John |  |
| 1 |  | New York |
| 2 |  | Seatle |
| 2 | Mike |  |

I am looking for a way to fetch log data in the following format combining empty and non-empty values

| id | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | New York |
| 2 | Mike | Seatle |

How can I achieve this using CloudWatch log filter query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible at the moment with just CloudWatch. There's nothing in the [log insights functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-operations-functions) that would do that.

You could try analyzing your logs in Athena, but that does add cost and complexity.  You can use the [CloudWatch / Athena connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-cloudwatch.html) which would let you query logs with SQL. Alternatively you could [export the logs to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html) for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by @Ed Eastwood, there is no built-in `join` function available in Cloudwatch with which you could easily achieve this. However, you can use a workaround using the `stats` command and the `sortsFirst` or `sortsLast` commands:

```
fields id, name, city
| stats count(*), sortsFirst(name), sortsFirst(city) by id
```

The above command would return you your desired table. Whether you use

Note however that this only works if you have a single value per column and unique id value, so it doesn't work exactly like a `join` would work.